# Limit scope of defined sort

Tags: z3, smt

I am trying to limit the scope of a newly defined sort via SMT-LIB. Doing so would simplify my script by reducing the amount of necessary assertions.

For this I played with *define-sort* and *forall*.

```
(define-sort R () Real)
(assert (forall ((x R)) (< 0 x)))
(declare-const r R)
(check-sat)
```

But z3 always returns *unsat* no matter what. So I guess this is not possible. Is it?

Comment: `(forall ...` is unsatisfiable because not all reals are larger than 0. You may be looking for an implication, e.g. `(forall ... (implies (< 0 x) (some other constraint))` so that some other constraint need only be true when x is larger than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in SMTLib. See this answer for details: [Is there an UnsignedIntSort in Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947126/is-there-an-unsignedintsort-in-z3)

As Christoph pointed out your query is `unsat` because the quantified assertion is false; which puts the solver in the `unsat` state, regardless of what other constraints you might have.

In my experience, the best way to deal with these scenarios is to not use SMTLib directly; but instead a higher-level API and use the programmatic features afforded by those environments to spit out all the `> 0` constraints as you need them. It's hairy and ugly, but it is the only way to deal with these in SMTLib as it stands today. The only solver that supported this sort of "predicate subtyping" was Yices v1.0 with its own input language, which is no longer supported.