# How to declare a natural number variable in z3py?

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I want to reason about natural numbers in my constraints.

I know that I can do something like:

`x = Int('x')` and then add a constraint that `x >= 0`. But is there a better way of doing this so that I don't have to add an additional constraint every time I declare a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "good" way to model naturals, unfortunately. Your best bet is to add `>= 0` constraints as needed. Note that you need to do this after every mathematical operation, especially subtraction.

If machine arithmetic is acceptable (i.e., modulo `2^n` for some `n`; typically `n=32` or `n=64`), then bit-vectors go far. Note that in SMTLib bit-vectors are unsigned, only the operations are. So you can get away without putting extra constraints of the form `>= 0` all the time. See [Is there an UnsignedIntSort in Z3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947126/is-there-an-unsignedintsort-in-z3) for a discussion.